# how to read a .properties file in a .xsl file using java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, properties-file

**Situation** : I have the following stylesheet/template

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" x   
    mlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body >
      <div align="center">
        <table border="1">          
          <tr>
            <td >
              <h1 >
                <span>@HEADER@</span>
              </h1>
              <div>
                <p>
                    @DETAIL@
                </p>
              </div>              
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also have a properties file that stores key-value pairs as follows :

```
DETAIL=This is format detail
HEADER=This is format header
```

**Problem** : i am trying to write a java program to transform the `xsl` into a `html` file and while doing so i want to substitute the values of keys specified in `.xsl` (enclosed within @) with their values mentioned in `.properties file` .My constraint is i cant modify `.xsl` file , i had tried `TransformerFactory` but it didn't work can anyone please help me in achieving this ?

Comment: You could use XSLT (2.0) to process the above XSLT document and replace any of the `@PROPERTY_NAME@` references with a global parameter `<xsl:param name="PROPERTY_NAME"/>` and `<xsl:value-of select="$PROPERTY_NAME"/>`, then you could run the new XSLT and pass in any properties you have in the properties file as parameters to the transformation. Note however that in your question's samples the names do not even match (e.g. `@HEADER@` versus `FORMAT_HEADER`).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to build a parametric XSL template where the parameters are in the property file.

Are the XSL and the property files very large?

If the files are small, you can read the XSL file row by row and use string substitution:

```
// preparing parsed template
File fout = new File("parsed.xsl");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

// preparing map for properties
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (final String name: properties.stringPropertyNames())
    map.put(name, properties.getProperty(name));

// read file and replace key with value 
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xslTemplate))) {
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        String temp = line.replace("@"+pair.getKey()+"@",pair.getValue());
        bw.write(temp);
        bw.newline();
  }
}
```

If the file are large, you may use this function in a different method used only for producing the parsed template and then using the new file in your normal execution.

If you call it in you Main.class, you can add an argument, for example "-c" and launch the program in the compile mode;

If you are using it in a Web Application, you can add the method call in a singleton with @Startup annotation and also called by the user when he change the XSL or the property file

I haven't tryed the code, maybe there are some syntax errors.
I hope the logic used in the parsing is simple.

Answer (score 0):

code to reading property file based on your locale.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:f="Functions"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

```
<!-- Code for reading proprty file -->
    <xsl:function name="f:getProperty" as="xs:string?">
        <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:string" />
        <xsl:variable name="lines" as="xs:string*"
            select="
                          for $x in 
                            for $i in tokenize($properties, '\n')[matches(., '^[^!#]')] return
                              tokenize($i, '=')
                            return translate(normalize-space($x), '\', '')" />
        <xsl:sequence select="$lines[index-of($lines, $key)+1]" />
    </xsl:function>
```

code to print message from property file.

```
<xsl:value-of select="f:getProperty('abc.xyz')" />
```